# Certificate validation failure while using cisco anyconnect with pfx certificates

Tags: linux, vpn, linux-mint, certificate, cisco-vpn-client

I have installed cisco anyconnect secure mobile client 4.2.01022 (+all required packages).

Then added `.pfx` certificates to `gnone2-key` storage.

Then I launched cisco anyconnect secure mobile client typed where to connect - but cisco keep saying me that `Certificate validation failure`

Tried this:

```
sudo cp /etc/ssl/certs/Global* /opt/.cisco/certificates/ca
```

link was created but didn't help. How to connect?

UPD:

This way I have extracted some certificates in different formats:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in store.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out domain.cer
openssl pkcs12 -in store.pfx -nocerts -nodes  -out domain.key
openssl pkcs12 -in store.pfx -out domain.crt -nodes -nokeys -cacerts
openssl pkcs12 -in  store.pfx  -nocerts -out domain.pem -nodes
```

Got 4 files:

```
domain.cer
domain.key
domain.crt
domain.pem
```

Placed all 4 of them in 3 different places:

```
~/.cisco/certificates/ca ~
```

Trusted CA and root certificates

```
~/.cisco/certificates/client
```

Client certificates

```
~/.cisco/certificates/client/private
```

Private keys

Same error.

UPD2: Tried to configure cisco anyconnect  compatible with openconnect (which integrated to linux network center):
It asks to set:

```
CA certificate (it has to be domain.crt, so chosen it)
User certificate  (that is it? - didnt choose)
Private key  (I think its domain.key, so chosen it)
```

But if tries to connect:

```
Certificate from VPN server [host ip] failed verification.
Reason: certificate does not match hostname
Do you want to accept it?

    Certificate from VPN server "194.176.96.4" failed verification.
    Reason: certificate does not match hostname
    Do you want to accept it?

With below info:
X.509 Certificate Information:
    Version: 3
    Serial Number (hex): ****
    Issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,OU=www.digicert.com,CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018
    Validity:
       Not Before: **
        Not After: **
    Subject: C=RU,ST=[city],L=[city],O=[company name],OU=IT,CN=vpn.[companyname].ru
    Subject Public Key Algorithm: RSA
    Algorithm Security Level: Medium (2048 bits)
....
```

I accept - and same error Certificate validation failure, full log:

```
POST https://[host_name]/
Attempting to connect to server [host_name]:443
SSL negotiation with [host_name]
Server certificate verify failed: certificate does not match hostname
Connected to HTTPS on [host_name]
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Sun, 26 Aug 2018 08:43:32 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Aggregate-Auth: 1
HTTP body chunked (-2)
Server requested SSL client certificate; none was configured
POST https://[host_name]/
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Sun, 26 Aug 2018 08:43:32 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Aggregate-Auth: 1
HTTP body chunked (-2)
XML POST enabled
```

PS: On windows same steps worked, added cert by double clicking then launched cisco client, typed server, then he asked password to server I quess - and then I was connected.

Comment: Can you try connection again and copy the logs from `system.log` and share it on any external file sharing server ? I can take a look. Also [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413646/converting-pfx-to-pem-using-openssl) on how to get private key, pem file from pfx.

Answer (score 4):

AnyConnect supports PEM format client certificates for authentication. Check [administrator guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect40/administration/guide/b_AnyConnect_Administrator_Guide_4-0/configure-vpn.html#ID-1428-000005ac) on how to configure client certificates for Linux platform. Copy the client certificate to the folder `~/.cisco/certificates/client` and the private key to `~/.cisco/certificates/client/private`. Also -

- All certificate files must end with the extension .pem.
- All private key files must end with the extension .key.
- A client certificate and its corresponding private key must have the 
  same filename. For example: client.pem and client.key.

Comment: I have extracted - same error. Such folder I had to create manually - is it ok? Because I'm sure that cisco actually look at that folders

Comment: Yes, user is expected to create those folders. Installer will not create these.

Answer (score 1):

You can use openconnect:

- Install it:

`sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome`

- Convert `.pfx` cert to `.pem`

`openssl pkcs12 -in file.pfx -out file.pem -nodes`

- In your GNOME / KDE open `Settings` > `Network` menu. In standard VPN settings you should see `Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN` item:
  [Network menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKJBc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, though I'm not sure i'm using the mobile version of AnyConnect. My OS is Fedora 29. The VPN I'm trying to connect to uses a browser trusted certificate, but not one bundled with the version of Anyconnect I had installed.

The package `ca-certificates` was already installed on my OS, and ships the necessary certificate, so I symlinked `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem` to `/opt/.cisco/certificates/ca`.